# access local webserver via putty ssh reverse tunnel

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

So I have a local webserver (http://localhost:8090) running on my machine. I would like to access this from a remote server (let's say 10.10.1.1) using putty reverse ssh tunnel. I setup it like this.

[putty tunnel setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAb6k.png)

Tried to test using curl but unable to connect.

```
curl -u admin:admin -X GET "http://localhost:8090/rest/api/content?" --connect-timeout 60
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: What's the operational system on your local machine and "10.10.1.1"? Linux?

Comment: Can you check PuTTY's event log? (Ctrl+right click the PuTTY window, select "Event Log".)

Comment: @FrancisconSantos, sorry missed to mention. local machine is windows and remote server is linux.

Comment: @user1686 this is the last two lines in event log.
2021-02-02 17:29:07 Requesting remote port 8090 forward to localhost:8090
2021-02-02 17:29:07 Remote port forwarding from 8090 enabled